# Como capturar uma tecla pressionada no C#

Tags: c#, winforms, teclado

Tenho uma aplicação com botões de dígitos e quero capturar as teclas digitadas e executar os eventos desses botões. Adicionei um evento de `keypress` na janela e tentei captar a tecla digitada, porém não consegui.

Código:

```
private void CalculadoraDS2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyChar.GetType == '0')
    {
        btn0.PerformClick();
    }
}
```

Comment: A propriedade `KeyPreview` do formulário tem que estar setada para `true` para que você possa manipular este evento. Você já checou ela?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda o atributo "KeyCode" não existe, e é Windows Form Application

Comment: @gato Eu modifiquei ela e não funcionou ...

Comment: @DanielSantos da [uma olhada aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx) to sem tempo para responder agora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue código:

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.D0)
{
    //tecla 0 pressionada
    btn0.PerformClick();
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Para mais informação: [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar(v=vs.110).aspx).

Lista completa de todos os códigos-chave **`Keys Enum`**: [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DPT-BR%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Keys);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.1).

Comment: if(e.KeyChar ==  '0') tambem